# Forms and CSS Questions

Tags: html, css, webforms

1) Is there a way to completely hide the IE scrollbar on textareas? (I'm primarily concerned with IE8) overflow: hidden or auto don't seem to work.

2) Is there a way to stop safari and chrome from "highlighting" focused form elements?

3) Is there a way to disable resizing of textareas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. overflow:hidden;
2. outline: none; (on the :focus pseudo-class of the element)
3. resize: none;

Comment: what does your doctype look like - this could be IE8 behaving in quirks mode.

Comment: @Matt It's strict right now - I'll mess around with it. I *thought* I was following that doctype, but probably not.

Comment: Have a read up on ie's quirksmode to see what you need to do. I'm on my mobile at the moment so a links a bit tricky :)

Comment: @Matt - that fixed it more  or less. I need it hidden because the text area automatically resizes - when it resizes, the scroll bar flashes up for a bit :/

Comment: Flickering scrollbar in IE8: http://www.freelists.org/post/dokuwiki/IE8-compatibility,10 - Sounds like its a compatibility mode issue.

Answer (score 1):

*If worse comes to worst*, you can absolute position a div on top of the scrollbar to hide it.